# SPRESENSE SDKのLTE Azure-IoT サンプルアプリケーションのビルドが失敗する

Tags: spresense

下記のサイトを参考にSPRESENSE SDKにあるLTE Azure-IoT サンプルアプリケーションを行っています。
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_tutorials_ja.html
しかしビルドをすると
mbedtls/md.h: No such file or directory
といったエラー文が出て、失敗してしまいます。
コンフィグは、サイト通りに
Application Configuration -> Spresense SDK -> Examples -> Azure IoT using LTE example

- Access Point Name (CONFIG_EXAMPLES_LTE_AZUREIOT_APN_NAME)
- IP type Selection (CONFIG_EXAMPLES_LTE_AZUREIOT_APN_IPTYPE_*)
- Authentication type Selection (CONFIG_EXAMPLES_LTE_AZUREIOT_APN_AUTHTYPE_*)
- Username used for authentication (CONFIG_EXAMPLES_LTE_AZUREIOT_APN_USERNAME)
- Password used for authentication (CONFIG_EXAMPLES_LTE_AZUREIOT_APN_PASSWD)
  を変更しています。
  原因や解決策がわかる方が居ましたら、是非教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こんにちは。
エラー内容から予想するに、MbedTLSのコンフィグが有効になっていないようです。
Spresense SDKのチュートリアルの通り、

```
$ tools/config.py examples/lte_azureiot
```

コマンドを使ってAzureIoTの必要なコンフィグをした後、

```
$ tools/config.py -m
```

コマンドを使って、AzureIoTで使用するAPN情報を更新する事で正しくビルドできるようになると思います。

次のコマンドを使うと↑の2つのコマンドをまとめることができるようです。

```
$ tools/config.py examples/lte_azureiot -m
```

ご参考になれば嬉しいです。